# fatal: http://gitlab.XXXXXXXXXX/talented/userName.git/info/refs not valid: is this a Git repository?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-bash

I have an account in GitLab by this Username and password:

in this URL: https://gitlab.com/

```
UserName: UsernameTest

Password: Password Test
```

Somebody send the link for me in GitLab by this address: http://gitlab.ConpmanyName.net:10201/talented/projectName

and gave me a Username and password:

```
Username: name

Password: somewords
```

Now, I need to clone the project with this URL `http://gitlab.compoanyName.net/talented/projName.git`

but it shows me this error:

> fatal: http://gitlab.compoanyName.net/talented/projName.git/info/refs
>   not valid: is this a git repository?

What's the problem? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If it shows the error without even asking for the username/password, check if you have a git credential helper caching the wrong credentials (`git config credential/helper`)

That or the URL is not the correct one (typically, it should be an HTTPS one, not an HTTP)

But if it (the remote company GitLab server) asks for credentials, and you enter said username / password (not the gitlab.com ones) and they don't work:

- either the password is not correct
- or it is correct, but would need to be [percent encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters) because of special characters
- or it does not have special characters, but [2FA was activated on that account](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/account/two_factor_authentication.html), and you would need a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) instead of your password.

Answer (score 0):

The error states your problem the url you used is not a valid git repository 
Git repository in gitlab will end with .git.

use

```
git clone http://gitlab.compoanyName.net/talented/projName.git
```

If this doesn't work.
 
Make sure its valid is to open the url in a browser and copy the url from the blue clone button on the right.

[image]